# Accelerometer in a QHO

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

This is an extension of a [previous idea](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03763) where the authors proposed to put a microorganism on a mechanical oscillator. However, I can't ask the bacterium how it "feels" to be standing on a superposition state or how it "feels" when its floor gets measured.

1. Trap a recording accelerometer in a harmonic potential
2. Initialise the motional state in the ground state $|0\rangle$
3. Displace the accelerometer motional state. This is to mark our reference in time in the reading of the accelerometer.
4. Initialise the motional state in the ground state $|0\rangle$
5. Prepare the motion in a superposition of Fock states, such as
   $|0\rangle+|N\rangle$, where $N>0$
6. Measure the motional state
7. Download the accelerometer reading

**What would had the accelerometer read?**

My wild guess is that

- If motion projected to $|0\rangle$ then this would answer the question **How does it "feel" to stand on a superposition?**. The total acceleration integrated over time would be $0$, i.e., any effect on the acceleration from the superposition of step 5 would be undone at the measurement event.
- If motion projected to $|N\rangle$, then this would answer **how does it "feel" when its floor gets measured?**. The accelerometer would measure a narrow peak in the acceleration, and the width of that peak is the time it took for the motion to collapse, i.e., the measurement event was not instantaneous.

Comment: A "quantum harmonic potential" is the same as a harmonic potential. I don't know what the |1> state is supposed to be. Do you mean the first excited state? If we make a (minimal) measurement on the first excited state, then we either force the system to be in the ground state, the first excited state or the second state after the measurement. All we have done is to remove a quantum of energy from the oscillator or to add a quantum of energy to it. That doesn't give us a trajectory from which an acceleration could be extracted. For that we would need much higher excited states.

Comment: @FlatterMann hope the edit clarifies that these are Fock states, and made clear that one can use an arbitrarily high excited state for the superposition

Comment: It still doesn't do anything for you. "Acceleration" only follows from a trajectory, which only follows from a large number of consecutive measurements. An accelerometer is harmonic oscillator itself, so in the quantum case now we are dealing with two coupled quantum harmonic oscillators.